# Calculating the integral $\frac{x}{1 + \sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to calculate the following integral:
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1 + \sqrt{x}}
$$
I have tried a subtitution of $u = \sqrt{x}$, gives $x = u^2$ and $dx/du = 2u$, so $dx = 2u du$. But then I get 
$$
2 \int_0^1 \frac{u^3}{1 + u}
$$
Still no idea how to proceed. I have thought about using $\ln(x)$ or $\arctan(x)$ but I'm stuck. Anyone knows how to calculate it?

Comment: Remark that you can now substitute $v=1+u$ and end up with lab bhattacharjee solution. Linear transformations are the simplest but are often overviewed when doing integrals, although they often lead to dramatic simplifications.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that is very helpful indeed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Start with $$\sqrt x+1=u\implies x=(u-1)^2,dx=2(u-1)\ du$$

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how you get $x = u^2-1$, I got $x = (u-1)^2$.

Comment: @Sigurd, Welcome. Thanks for upur observation.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{u^{3}}{u+1}&=\dfrac{(u+1-1)^{3}}{u+1}\\
&=\dfrac{(u+1)^{3}-3(u+1)^{2}+3(u+1)-1}{u+1}\\
&=(u+1)^{2}-3(u+1)+3-\dfrac{1}{u+1},
\end{align*}
then
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}(u+1)^{2}du=\dfrac{1}{3}(u+1)^{3}\bigg|_{u=0}^{u=1}=\cdots
\end{align*}
and the last one is 
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{u+1}du=\log(u+1)\bigg|_{u=0}^{u=1}=\cdots
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Just make the division of $x^3$ by $1+u$. You'll obtain
$$\int_0^1 p(u)\,\mathrm du+\int_0^1 \frac 1{1+u}\,\mathrm du,$$
where $p(u)$ is a quadratic polynomial.